# Uploaded package not showing in my Launchpad PPA

Tags: ubuntu, deb, launchpad

I created a package for Launchpad PPA and want to upload it to Launchpad. I've used dput command and this is what I get:

```
tomica@home:~/Desktop$ dput ppa:{MY_LAUNCHPAD}/ppa packagename_0.0.1_source.changes
Uploading packagename using ftp to ppa (host: ppa.launchpad.net; directory: ~{MY_LAUNCHPAD}/ppa)
running supported-distribution: check whether the target distribution is currently supported (using distro-info)
{'allowed': ['release'], 'known': ['release', 'proposed', 'updates', 'backports', 'security']}
running required-fields: check whether a field is present and non-empty in the changes file
running checksum: verify checksums before uploading
running suite-mismatch: check the target distribution for common errors
running check-debs: makes sure the upload contains a binary package
running gpg: check GnuPG signatures before the upload
Uploading packagename_0.0.1.dsc
Uploading packagename_0.0.1.tar.gz
Uploading packagename_0.0.1_source.buildinfo
Uploading packagename_0.0.1_source.changes
tomica@home:~/Desktop$
```

I would think that this means my upload was successful. However, [when I visit my PPA, it's empty](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomicakorac/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages). Why is that?

If I try to upload my package again, this is what I get:

```
tomica@home:~/Desktop$ dput ppa:{MY_LAUNCHPAD}/ppa packagename_0.0.1_source.changes
Package packagename was already uploaded to ppa
If you want to upload nonetheless, use --force or remove packagename_0.0.1_source.ppa.upload
tomica@home:~/Desktop$
```

This means that my package should be visible and accessible, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, here's the explanation:

1. The package was getting rejected because Launchpad builder could not parse non-latin name in 'Maintainer' field in debian/control file. This is considered a bug and was reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1910403
2. Because of the same bug, notification emails were not getting sent, and so I could not know what the reason was.

I found these answers by asking here: https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/694768.

Comment: How did you find out that it was rejected ? I have the same issue, I don't see my package in my ppa. and I do not know why

Comment: I've opened a question under Launchpad itself project in Launchpad on this address: https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad and one of the members helped.